# H-bridge -- Driver for bootstrapping High-side N-MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, gate-driving, powermosfet

I'm working on a design of an h-bridge for a student organization.

**Current Design**

[image: H-bridge drawing on LTSpice]

**Problem**
Controlling the N-Mosfets is simple -- supplying 5V to "on" and 0V to "off".

However, in order to control the P-Mosfets (on the high side), 36V-Vto = ~34V needs to be supplied, which is unfeasible by microcontroller.

**How might I get around this?** Ultimately, I'd want to be able to control the high-side switches using the same logic voltage as the low-side.

I understand that I can use an h-bridge driver IC (w/bootstrapping) such as [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2111.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c810e51682).

However, I have very limited knowledge as to how this works, how to choose the right IC/resistors/capacitors...

**Extra Notes**

1. Assume the current range through the load (symbolized by resistor + inductor combination) is 0->5A.
2. Assume the 'high-side voltage' is 36V and 'low-side voltage' is GND (as annotated).
3. Assume Vleft and Vright are the necessary voltages to turn on/off a given mosfet. Currently, they are 36V and 0V respectively (only for simulation purposes -- this is an unfeasible solution as described above).

Comment: How are you going to manage shoot-through if upper and lower MOSFETs are controlled by the same logic signal?

Comment: What is your load? What voltage range (36V and what else?), and current range? What kind of drive signals will be used (frequency range, duty cycle range, dead time, start/stop/burst stats, etc.)? There are dozens of gate drive circuits and variants, with many reasons to choose them; it sounds like it will be easier if we select for you, rather than list them all out.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm afraid I'm not familiar with shoot-through in this situation. I would be turning on mosfets on opposite sides (high-left and low-right OR high-right and low-left) and so the voltage will drop over the load. I didn't think there would be a direct path from source->gnd so as to cause shoot-through? Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: @TimWilliams As pictured,
Load is: 3ohm R + 10m Inductor. Assume the current through it is in the range of 0->5A. I know this doesn't follow ohm's law, but assume that the max current would be 5A. I'm not sure what you mean by voltage range. It will always be 36V.

Comment: There's no need to be cagey, you can say it's a brushed DC motor or whatever. Generally the more supporting and background information given, the better an answer can be.

Comment: Accidentally hit enter before adding this:

duty-cycle range: nominally 50%
freq range: 500 Hz and 10KHz (relatively low)

Comment: Yeah, my intention isn't to be cagey. The project is part of a student org -- it isn't a brushed DC motor as such. Rather, it is a coil of wire wrapped around a steel core -- to be used as an electromagnet with varying current. We are representing that load as an inductor and resistor.

Comment: Do you use only single low side PWM with the opposite high side FET static on, or do you need full active swing on both sides? Your schematic shows four identical FETs but 2 symbols are N-FETs and two are P-FETs. Which is correct?

Comment: The schematic shows 2 N-FETs and 2 P-FETs. However, I would like to substitute this for 4 N-FETs with bootstrapping as that seems to be the most ideal way to control directionality from a microcontroller IO pin (which cannot supply the 34V needed to turn on Pmosfet). 

So, I suppose this would mean that I need to turn opposite FETs on at a given time (low-left + high-right OR low-right + high-left). I'm not sure if this answers the question... @Jens

Comment: Well, I asked because most of these driver ICs cannot continuously hold the high side FETs in a conducting state. After some time (typically < 1 ms) they need a short switching cycle to recharge the boost capacitor. This is not a problem if you create a PWM on both bridge sides anyway, but if you need constant conduction of a high side FET, you need a different circuit with active charge pump or you use PFETs.

Comment: Oh I see. No, I will not need to continuously hold a high-side FET on. This is being used in a device where the direction will be toggled frequently. But I'm not really understanding the device specs. What do VS mean here would this work for the schematic pictured? Or would I need the Vout to be >=36